# Testing http.Pusher and the push function in golang

Tags: http, go, testing, http2

I am trying to write a unit test for http.Pusher. I tried using httptest.NewRecorder() as http.ResponseWriter but the type conversion failed. How else can I write the test?

```
    //My function 
    func push(w http.ResponseWriter, resource string) error {
        pusher, ok := w.(http.Pusher)
        if ok {
            return pusher.Push(resource, nil)
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("Pusher not supported")
    }

    //My test 
    func TestPush(t *testing.T) {
        resource := "static/css/main.css"
        response := httptest.NewRecorder()
        got := push(response, resource)

        if got != nil {
            t.Errorf("Error : %v", got)
        }
    }
```

The output is "Pusher not supported", which I assume that w.(http.Pusher) failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a mocked [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) that also implements [`http.Pusher`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Pusher), and pass that during testing.

Here's a simple implementation that suits your testable function:

```
type pusher struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    err    error // err to return from Push()
    target string
    opts   *http.PushOptions
}

func (p *pusher) Push(target string, opts *http.PushOptions) error {
    // record passed arguments for later inspection
    p.target = target
    p.opts = opts
    return p.err
}
```

Example test function:

```
func TestPush(t *testing.T) {
    resource := "static/css/main.css"
    p := &pusher{}
    err := push(p, resource)

    if err != p.err {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %v, got: %v", p.err, err)
    }
    if resource != p.target {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %v, got: %v", p.target, resource)
    }
}
```

Note that this simple `pusher` embeds the `http.ResponseWriter` type which will make it itself an `http.ResponseWriter` (it will make `pusher` implement `http.ResponseWriter`). During the test we left this field `nil` because the testable `push()` function did not use anything from it. If your real function would call methods of it such as `ResponseWriter.Header()`, that would cause a runtime panic of course. In that case you have to provide a valid `http.ResponseWriter` too, e.g.:

```
p := &pusher{ResponseWriter: httptest.NewRecorder()}
```